# Add navigation for paging control of each slide in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add paging control of each slide in [this](http://panicstation.pixelthrone.com/html/) website background slideshow.

Flexslider is used here. The javascript for the slider will be available in main.js.

I have added the code below to enable the paging control but nothing is showing up.

```
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({

    // Primary Controls
    controlNav: true,               //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage
    directionNav: true,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
    prevText: "Previous",           //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
    nextText: "Next",               //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: false,
    smoothHeight: true,
    animation: "none",
});
```

Supersized in main.js:

```
if (typeof pt_supersized_slides !== "undefined")
{
    jQuery.supersized({
        slide_interval : 100000, // Length between transitions
        transition : 1, // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed : 500, // Speed of transition
        slide_links : 0, // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'number', 'name', 'blank')
        slides : pt_supersized_slides

    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to apply this for what you want paging.

Answer (score 0):

The id of the slider on your website is "supersized" not "flexslider" and I don't see any class name of "flexslider" in your source code.

Comment: I have added some code for supersized above. Check if I missed out something there.

Comment: You didn't get it. What your problem is not your js above, it's element class name DOES NOT MATCH. If you look at your page source code, there is no class name of "flexslider", so how do you suppose it to work with your jquery selector? And the supersized part you put in here, apparently it has no kind of nav control attribute in it. My suggestion is either to add a class name of "flexslider" to your slider div or change that bit in your js. Either way mate you have to get them match!